# how to solve this compile error about ffmpeg 2.6 with android NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I got a compile error about the ffmpeg 2.6.
I used android-ndk-r10d. **How to solve it?**

```
libavformat/mov.c:653: error: undefined reference to 'avpriv_ac3_channel_layout_tab'
libavformat/mov.c:685: error: undefined reference to 'avpriv_ac3_channel_layout_tab'
libavformat/movenc.c:4818: error: undefined reference to 'avpriv_pix_fmt_bps_mov'
libavformat/movenc.c:1359: error: undefined reference to 'avpriv_pix_fmt_bps_mov'
libavformat/utils.c:3375: error: undefined reference to 'avcodec_pix_fmt_to_codec_tag'
libavformat/utils.c:3376: error: undefined reference to 'avpriv_get_raw_pix_fmt_tags'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order should be like this:

```
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += libavformat libavcodec libswresample libswscale libavutil
```